# ng-show is Hiding All Content On Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

**Here is my scenario:**

I'm creating a sidebar menu with AngularJS. When the user selects the **hamburger** icon, it should slide the menu to the right. When the user selects the **remove** button, the menu should slide to the left (off the screen).

**Current Scenario:**

The menu opens and closes as expected. However, the rest of the content on the page disappears when the menu opens. I've spent time looking on the web, but cannot isolate the issue. Any tips or suggestions?

**Here is my repository:**

> https://bitbucket.org/ChaseHardin/teaplanner/

**Code:**

**Controller**

```
"use strict";

teaApp.controller("menuController", function($scope) {
    $scope.toggled = false;

    $scope.toggle = function() {
        $scope.toggled = !$scope.toggled;
    }
});
```

**View**

```
 <div ng-controller="menuController">
        <h3 class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" id="menu-align-hamburger" ng-click="toggle()" ng-show="!toggled"></h3>
        <div class="menu-box" ng-show="toggled">
            <h3 class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" id="menu-align-remove" ng-click="toggle()"></h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1 class="text-center">Hello StackOverflow!!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu-box {
    background-color: #403b41;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
}

#menu-align-hamburger {
    padding-left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer
}

#menu-align-remove {
    padding-left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: dimgrey;
}
```

Comment: It's almost certainly a background overlay designed to create a modal appearance.  You'll need to inspect the rest of the content to see if an overlay is present.  There's no way for us to identify it based on what you've posted, since it most likely is not related.

Comment: @DavidL I'm not really sure what you mean by background overlay. Could you expand? Here is my repo: https://bitbucket.org/ChaseHardin/teaplanner/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your menu expands, it ends up taking up the entire content area, pushing your "Hello" text below the sidebar.

Create a more flexible layout, such as applying `display:inline-block` to both the menu and the content area will cause the content to simply "move over" when the menu opens rather than getting pushed below the menu.

P.S., if you scroll down far enough, you'll see that your content is still there.  it's just hidden from view, depending on your resolution.

Comment: I totally overlooked this. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!  Much easier to identify with a second set of eyes :).